# How can I specify that I only want Spot Instances for my Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spot-instances

My `env.yaml` has:

```
  aws:ec2:instances:
    InstanceTypes: g4dn.xlarge,c5.4xlarge,r5.2xlarge,r5a.xlarge
    EnableSpot: true
    SpotMaxPrice: "0.15"
```

but when I do `eb create`, it still asks me:

```
Would you like to enable Spot Fleet requests for this environment?
(y/N): y
Enter a list of one or more valid EC2 instance types separated by commas (at least two instance types are recommended).
(Defaults provided on Enter):
```

Why is it not respecting the `env.yaml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify that you don't want any on-demand instances you can use [SpotFleetOnDemandBase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2instances) and [SpotFleetOnDemandAboveBasePercentage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2instances):

- SpotFleetOnDemandBase: The minimum number of On-Demand Instances that your Auto Scaling group **provisions before considering Spot Instances** as your environment scales up.
- SpotFleetOnDemandAboveBasePercentage: The percentage of **On-Demand Instances** as part of additional capacity that your Auto Scaling group provisions beyond the SpotOnDemandBase instances.

The use of the options is exemplified in [Example 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-purchase-options.html#asg-instances-distribution). Specifically, if **both options are set to `0`**, no on-demand instances will be used.

Comment: I have those set and when I do eb create, it still asks me which instance types I want.

Comment: @Shamoon I think you provide them for the spot fleet, so that cheapest spots are selected from the preferred types.